# Is a scroll destroyed when you fail the spellcaster level check?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

The rules on scrolls state:

> A spell on a scroll can be used only once. The writing vanishes from the scroll when the spell is activated.
>
> (...)
>
> If she meets all three requirements but her own caster level is lower than the scroll spell's caster level, then she has to make a caster level check (DC = scroll's caster level + 1) to cast the spell successfully.

If the caster level check fails but without Mishap, is the spell "activated" or not? Is the scroll destroyed if you fail?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The FAQ at the bottom of the SRD's page for [scrolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/scrolls) answers exactly this question:

> If I fail my caster level check to activate a scroll, but don't have a
>   mishap, is the scroll used up?
>
> No. In the Activation section, in the first paragraph after the bullet
>   points, add the following sentence: **"If the caster level check fails
>   but no mishap occurs, the scroll is not expended."**